# Check Document Set files columns and dialog box

Tags: document-set

I have a Document Library with Document Set Content types and hence Document Sets.
The document library has a date column called `LiveDate` next to the Document Sets
Within the Document Set I have documents (contracts) and a column called `ContractDate` and `ContractStatus`.

1. I want to run a workflow on the Contracts that copies the `ContractDate` to the `LiveDate`.
2. Also, if possible when the workflow is executed I want the `ContractDate` copied to the  `LiveDate` if no contracts has a `ContractStatus=Live`. If a Live status of any contract is in existence in the Document Set an error is displayed. Hence I need to iterate the Document Set and check Contract Status.

Someone suggested:
*You may need to look at using the ‘Lists.asmx’ (http:///_vti_bin/Lists.asmx) web service with the ‘UpdateListItems’ method to update your fields. If you are wanting to do this for a number of items you could utilize a foreach loop to iterate through each item in the document set and execute the web service call.*

Dont fully understand suggestion, should I use client serviced like SPServices to accomplish this or Event Receiver or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Nintex for your workflows then it will allow you to loop and make a call to the web service all within the workflow.

Another approach may be to run a workflow every time a document is added or edited to check the status and update the parent item?

You could also embed some jQuery on the Document Set page which checked all the contained documents but this would only trigger when the page was visited so may not meet your requirements.

Comment: If I use Nintex and loop to check status why and how do I call a web service?
I tried updating the Parent item using two options being Nintex workflow and also tried coding an event receiver. I couldnt get neither to work. Any guidance helpful.

Comment: I think one of the problems with my requirements is client side interaction use (dialog box alert) and server side workflows to update the parent.. These dont work well together. Hence client side only solution may be best option.. Any views?

Comment: There is a Call Web Service action which I was assuming you would use to update the parent item but there may be a simpler way to refer to it.  That said, I think the middle option I outlined is probably the better alternative

Comment: Hi Option 2 does sound straight forward however I'm having difficulties obtaining the browser address (which contains the Parent ID).Any ideas how to obtain this? Thanks

Comment: There are a couple of lookup values in Nintex that give you the path which you can then manipulate with regex to get the name of the document set.

Comment: Hi I could not find a way to get the url hence I cannot access the ID. Are you sure this is possible? Which action does it?